# Term not found in list, ValueError: list.index(x): x not in list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a notepad full of different materials and I was asked to sort them into a user-friendly readable statement.

For example if my `material_list` contains `['Wool', 'Cotton']` It will output `'Wool & Cotton'`

But if my material_list contains `['Wool', 'Aloe', 'Fiber']` it will output `'Wool & Aloe Fiber'`.

I implemented this became sometimes I have `'Silk'`, but if I have `'Bamboo'` and `'Silk'` in my list, that means it is `'Bamboo Silk'`.

I do not have to worry about the case when I have `['Bamboo','Banana','Silk']`.

```
# List of all Materials
materials = [
    'Aloe', 'Alpaca', 'Bamboo', 'Banana', 'Cotton',
    'Cowhide', 'Fiber', 'Hemp', 'Jute', 'Lambskin',
    'Leather', 'Linen', 'Paper', 'Polyester', 'Polypropylene',
    'Seagrass', 'Shearling', 'Sheepskin', 'Silk', 'Sisal',
    'Tencel', 'Viscose', 'Wool' , 'Yard'
               ] 

def FindMaterial(toPrint,database):
    material_list = []
    for x in range (0,len(database)):
        if database[x].lower() in toPrint.lower():
            material_list.append(database[x])

    #Special cases for certain combinations of materials
    def SpecialCases(mat1,mat2):
        if mat1 and mat2 in material_list:
            material_list.remove(mat1)
            material_list.remove(mat2)
            material_list.append(mat1+' '+mat2)
    SpecialCases('Aloe','Fiber')
    SpecialCases('Bamboo','Silk')
    SpecialCases('Banana','Silk')   
    SpecialCases('Wool','Sisal')

    if len(material_list) == 1:
        material_string = (material_list[0])
    else:
        material_string = (material_list[0]+' & '+material_list[1])

    return material_string
```

`FindMaterial(sample_input,materials)`

Something like `sample_input = ['Silk']` causes the error `ValueError: list.index(x): x not in list` on the line `material_list.remove(mat1)`

`'Wool'` produced no error. I'm aware that `'Fiber'` alone or `'Sisal'` alone produced the same error but these two terms will never appear alone, only `'Silk'` can.

Comment: Also update the question on how you are calling the function, what is `database` ?

Comment: Sorry I edited the question and added `FindMaterial(sample_input,materials)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if mat1 and mat2 in material_list:
```

I think you've got a bug if you're trying to determine if both mat1 and mat2 are in material_list.  Try

```
if mat1 in material_list and mat2 in material_list:
```

Comment: This worked! I wanted to ask what is the difference between the two logically? Would I ever want to use `if mat1 and mat2 in material_list:`?

Comment: (mat1) and (mat2 in material_list) as opposed to (mat1 in material_list) and (mat2 in material_list).  So, mat1 is almost always evaluated as True in the context of the and operator, unless mat1 is False or None, a numeric zero, an empty string, ... (there are more exceptions) The boolean operator story can be found here: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations